# Why does `select` continue to think I need to `accept`?

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I'm trying to write a simple socket server, for the sake of this example it's an echo server.

This is socket_server.c (note the comment about where it gets stuck)

```
int fdmax, i, socket_descriptor;
fd_set master, read_fds;
struct timeval tv = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 1000};

void socket_server_init(void)
{
    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
}

socket_server_socket socket_server_start(char *socket_path)
{
    struct sockaddr_un local;
    int len;
    int socket_descriptor = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socket_descriptor == -1)
        return (socket_server_socket) {.status = SOCKET_SERVER_START_SOCKET_FAILURE, .descriptor = -1};

    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, socket_path);
    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);

    if (bind(socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1)
        return (socket_server_socket) {.status = SOCKET_SERVER_START_BIND_FAILURE, .descriptor = -1};

    if (listen(socket_descriptor, 5) == -1)
        return (socket_server_socket) {.status = SOCKET_SERVER_START_LISTEN_FAILURE, .descriptor = -1};

    FD_SET(socket_descriptor, &master);
    fdmax = socket_descriptor;
    return (socket_server_socket) {.status = 0, .descriptor = socket_descriptor};
}

socket_server_socket socket_server_wait_for_connection(socket_server_socket server)
{
    read_fds = master;
    select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    for (i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds))
        {
            if (i == server.descriptor)
            {
                // It's getting stuck here.
                socket_descriptor = accept(server.descriptor, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);

                if (socket_descriptor > fdmax)
                    fdmax = socket_descriptor;

                FD_SET(socket_descriptor, &master);
                return (socket_server_socket) {.status = -1, .descriptor = socket_descriptor};
            } else {
                return (socket_server_socket) {.status = 0, .descriptor = i};
            }
        }
    }

    return (socket_server_socket) {.status = -1, .descriptor = -1};
}

int socket_server_update(socket_server_socket client)
{
    char buffer[256];
    int n = recv(client.descriptor, buffer, 256, 0);
    if (n < 0)
        return SOCKET_SERVER_UPDATE_RECV_FAILURE;

    if (send(client.descriptor, buffer, n, 0) < 0)
        return SOCKET_SERVER_UPDATE_SEND_FAILURE;

    close(client.descriptor);
    return 0;
}
```

Then in my main program:

```
    socket_server_init();
    socket_server_socket server = socket_server_start(SOCKET_PATH);
    while (1) {
        printf("wait for conn\n");
        socket_server_socket client = socket_server_wait_for_connection(server);

        if (client.status == 0)
        {
            socket_server_update(client);
        }

        sleep(1);
        printf("%d: Log !\n", (int)time(NULL));
    }
```

When I run the program I observe:

1. "Log !" is output on the console
2. I connect to the server through the socket
3. I continue to see "Log !" on the console
4. I sent some data from the client
5. The client sees the data echo back
6. "Log !" is no longer being seen on the console
7. Any subsequent data from the client is not echoed back

I expect the loop to carry on and "Log !" to continue to be output, but it looks like my program is getting stuck at the `accept` call, but only the second time.

As I understand it, `select` is only supposed to add the descriptor to `read_fds` if it needs to be accepted or recv'd. So what seems to happen is:

1. `select` adds the server's descriptor to `read_fds`
2. It gets accepted
3. `select` again adds the servers descriptor to `read_fds`
4. There is nothing waiting to be `accept`ed so `accept` hangs

I've verified that both times when the `accept` call is reached, the descriptor is the same. So I'm very confused.

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it shouldn't be hitting `accept` a second time for the same connection.

Answer (score 1):

You use a timeout, if this timeout passes, `select(2)` would return 0, your program doesn't care about its return value and treat it as a successful call ("We have something to read"), but `read_fds` hasn't  been updated. Therefore, it still hold its previous value ("We have a new client"), then, you call `accept` and get stuck.

The solution would be very easy: check `select(2)`'s return value:

```
 int result = select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
 if (result < 0) {
     // Handle error.
 } else if (result == 0) {
     // Handle timeout.
 }
```

To learn more about `select` and sockets in unix in common, I highly recommend reading [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select).

Comment: This seems close... I can't follow your suggestion though because that causes select to block while it waits for a connection. I'm using a timeout so that other parts of my program can continue working. I did try `if (select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0) return;` but then I get in a situation where `select` just keeps returning -1 for some reason.

Comment: Keep in mind that you should `FD_CLR` invalid (closed) sockets from your `fd_set`. .  Please try to follow beej's example for a simple chat and compare it to your program. To see why select is returning -1, try to print the last error with `perror`.

Comment: @CameronBall if select returns 0 you have a time out. If it returns <0 you have an *error* and you need to check errno and/or use perror or whatever in irder to see what the error is.